# In Java, what do we mean by finalize gracefully?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
  package com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.main;

    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.initiation.Initiator;
    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.receiver.Receiver;

    /**
     * Starts application, Instantiate Players and help in garbage collection
     * 
     */
    public class MainApp {

        /**
         * main method instantiates Initiator and Receiver and helps in message
         * communication between them
         * 
         * Also sets unused objects to null and callss System.exit
         * 
         * @param args
         *            String array
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Instantiates Initiator
            Initiator initiatorPlayer = new Initiator();
            // Instantiates Receiver
            Receiver receiverPlayer = new Receiver();
            // start sending message
            initiatorPlayer.sendMessage(receiverPlayer);
            // sets the value of the unused instances to null for garbage collection
            initiatorPlayer = null;
            receiverPlayer = null;
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    package com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction;

    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.initiation.Initiator;

    /**
     * Parent class of {@link Initiator} and {@link Receiver}
     * 
     * @author Madhubanti Jash
     * 
     */
    public class Player {

        /**
         * returns counter value in string
         * 
         * @param counter
         *            1,2,3 etc
         * @return String format of counter
         */
        public String checkCounter(int counter) {
            switch (counter) {
            case 1:
                return "first";
            case 2:
                return "second";
            case 3:
                return "third";
            case 4:
                return "fourth";
            case 5:
                return "fifth";
            case 6:
                return "sixth";
            case 7:
                return "seventh";
            case 8:
                return "eighth";
            case 9:
                return "ninth";
            case 10:
                return "tenth";
            default:
                return "garbage collection";
            }
        }

    }

    package com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.initiation;

    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.Player;
    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.log.ConfigLogger;
    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.receiver.Receiver;

    /**
     * Initiates message communication with {@link Receiver} and receives new
     * message from it.
     * 
     * @author Madhubanti Jash
     * 
     */
    public class Initiator extends Player {

        /** initializes logger */
        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Initiator.class.getName());

        /**
         * sends message to Receiver and receives new message in return
         * 
         * @param receiverPlayer
         *            instance of Receiver
         * 
         */
        public void sendMessage(Receiver receiverPlayer) {
            ConfigLogger.addLoggerHandler(LOGGER);
            String message = "";
            String prefix = "Sent message for ";
            String postfix = " Time";
            for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
                message = prefix + super.checkCounter(counter) + postfix;
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, "message to be sent is: {0}", message);
                String newReceivedMessage = receiverPlayer.receiveMessage(message, counter);
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, "Received new message from Receiver is: {0}", newReceivedMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    package com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.receiver;

    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.Player;
    import com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.initiation.Initiator;

    /**
     * Receives message communication from {@link Initiator} and sends back new
     * message
     * 
     * @author Madhubanti Jash
     * 
     */
    public class Receiver extends Player {

        /**
         * receives message from initiator and sends back new message in return
         * 
         * @param message
         *            received message
         * @return newMessage new message to Initiator
         * 
         */
        public String receiveMessage(String message, int counter) {
            String messageForNullValue = "have not received message; so not returning new message.";
            String postfix = " time from Receiver class.";
            String receivedMessage = message;
            String prefix = "Received message for ";
            String checkCounter = checkCounter(counter);
            String counterString = " The counter is: ";
            String newMessage = receivedMessage == null ? messageForNullValue
                    : prefix + checkCounter + postfix + counterString + counter;
            return newMessage;
        }

    }

    package com.madhubanti.singleprocess.player.interaction.log;

    import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    /** responsible to add log level and handler */
    public class ConfigLogger extends Logger {

        /**
         * parameterized constructor
         * 
         * @param name
         *            A name for the logger
         * @param resourceBundleName
         *            name of resource bundle
         * 
         */
        protected ConfigLogger(String name, String resourceBundleName) {
            super(name, resourceBundleName);
        }

        /**
         * add log level and handler
         * 
         * @param logger
         *            LOGGER
         */
        public static void addLoggerHandler(Logger logger) {
            ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
            logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
            consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        }
    }
```

I have mentioned above 5 classes. Here Initiator initiates communication with Receiver. In response to that Receiver sends back message.
After 10 times of send and receiving messages, I want to finalize the not-required objects gracefully.

For that I have set values of `initiatorPlayer` and `receiverPlayer` as `null` after they have completed their work and then called `System.exit(0)` in MainApp.java. Is this the correct way to implement "finalize gracefully"?

Comment: No, you don't need to do any of the things in the stars. You don't need to do anything at all.

Comment: ... at least not in this code snippet.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose could you please provide an example where do we need to finalize gracefully and how do we do it?

Comment: What do you think finalize means? You need to learn that in order to have this question answered. In general though, you have 3 lines of code that are making your program less graceful in multiple ways and should be removed and not replaced.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I have not added the whole code snippet as there I have not added any code which sets unused objects to null. I know that we cannot force java garbage collector to collect any object. We can only send request. So my question was how I did it, does it work or requested if any elaborated example can be presented. I have just joined stack overflow today. So, my next question certainly would have much more details if required.

Comment: That is not what finalization refers to.

Comment: @Madhubanti no worries. You need to recheck your assumption. You seem to think that finalization is about requesting garbage collection but that is not true. A false premise will lead to a false conclusion. Before trying to write a graceful finalizer, read about what a finalizer is.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, The java.lang.Object.finalize() is called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object. I need an example where something meaningful is done in order to finalize gracefully.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. You need to understand the use case for writing a finalizer. Most classes do not provide them. You are thinking from B to A instead of A to B

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, could you make me understand?

Comment: Finalizers exist to assist in cleaning up resources that are _not_ handled by the GC. They allow a class to specify some arbitrary code that _may_ be run when an instance of that class is collected. This ties the lifetimes of GC managed resources and non-GC managed resources together. It is not related to setting variables to `null`. Please google for Java finalizers and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: @Aluan Hadded, I know about finalizer. I have doubt regarding "finalize gracefully". There google could not help me much. Could you give some example of "finalizing gracefully". Here the more  important term for me is gracefully.

Comment: How can you evaluate that without knowing what it would be to finalize?
 This is not about helping you cheat on homework assignments.

Comment: @Aluan Hadded I am sorry but I have to say you are very harsh. Who told that I do not know what is finalize? I want to know what is "finalize gracefully". It seems you do not know the answer and trying to deviate me from my main question. Stop seeing my thread if you can't answer rather getting into unnecessary discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalizing gracefully means generally finalizing in a way where tear down / unsetup operations may be invoked.
To allow that, you have to ensure that the application cannot terminate by a crash.

**Which is not required to finish gracefuly**

Setting variables to `null` is not required as all Java objects will be removed as the JVM is terminated. So you should remove these statements.

As well as invoking        `System.exit(0);` as you will get the same result by leaving the `main()` thread finishes its execution.

**Example where a graceful end matters**

Suppose that in your code, `Receiver` creates under the hood a resource not attached to the JVM such as a network socket to receive messages.
As the program is terminated, you want that all not needed any longer resources be properly disposed : the objects allocated by the running JVM but also the opened socket.
The JVM exit will not necessary close all resources attached to the socket.  Invoking `receiverPlayer.dipose()` could be the way to achieve that. 
But to do that you need to allow the program to finish gracefully.

For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
  Receiver receiverPlayer = null;
  try{
       // Instantiates Initiator
          Initiator initiatorPlayer = new Initiator();
       // Instantiates Receiver
          receiverPlayer = new Receiver();
       // start sending message
         initiatorPlayer.sendMessage(receiverPlayer); 
     }
  finally{
       if (receiverPlayer != null){
          receiverPlayer.dispose(); 
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I added a concrete example

Comment: @Madhubanti You are welcome :) No you don't. `dispose()` or `close()` are method names generally used to define such a behavior.  It if makes sense you can implement `java.io.Closeable`. You could so use the `try-with-resources` pattern that is another matter... Or else create your own method. The important thing is that the method  javadoc be clear and that you  perform all cleaning operations in the implementation of the method. That's all !